# Android: GridView return image path

Tags: android, gridview, image-gallery, absolute-path

I want to extract absolute path from image clicked in GridView.

Here's my code:

```
public class CustomGallery extends Activity {
private int count;
private Bitmap[] thumbnails;
private boolean[] thumbnailsselection;
private String[] arrPath;
private ImageAdapter imageAdapter;
ArrayList<String> f = new ArrayList<String>();// list of file paths
File[] listFile;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gallery);
    getFromSdcard();
    GridView imagegrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.PhoneImageGrid);
    imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter();
    imagegrid.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
    imagegrid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Private Folder Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}

public void getFromSdcard() {
    File file = new File("/storage/sdcard/DCIM");

    if (file.isDirectory()) {
        listFile = file.listFiles();

        for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {

            f.add(listFile[i].getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }
}

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public ImageAdapter() {
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return f.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.galleryitem, null);
            holder.imageview = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.thumbImage);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.get(position));
        holder.imageview.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
        return convertView;
    }

}

class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageview;

}
}
```

I know I have to write code in onitemclicklistener but I do not know how to make logic for it.

Please give me code for extraction of absolute path from item clicked. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this, this may help you

```
imagegrid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                    int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        f.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: I am trying to upvote it but my Reputation is less than 15. upvote isn't working. anyways i m tnkful to u for ur help.

Comment: oh yes, actually i didn't knew about this feature. saw it nw :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add

```
holder.imageview.setonClickListener
```

and inside that check the path of the File f by `f.getAbsolutePath();`

Check this -

You have to add this inside getView method, check this sample

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.galleryitem, null);
            holder.imageview = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.thumbImage);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.get(position));
        holder.imageview.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);


         holder.imageview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    System.out.println("Absolute Path :"+f.getAbsolutePath(););
                }
            });
        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: Sir can you please tell me where should i add these line of codes?

Comment: You have to add this inside getView method, i have added some sample code. Hope this helps.

Comment: Sir, f.getAbsolutePath() isn't working in this code. where i press g after f. i only get 2 options i.e. get and getclass

Comment: f is the file object, check and do modifications as per your code.

Comment: Sir, I am unable to do it. can u please do it for me. i tried a lot but still stuck in it